Calculating API Request Rate Over time by status code and path
I'm using the below expression to calculate the rate of requests by status_code and path:
 sum(rate(http_request_duration_seconds_count[10m])) by (status_code, path) > 0


I'm getting abnormally high values like 30req/s - I do not think my site is handling so many concurrent users.
When looking at the http_request_duration_seconds_count metric in prometheus I see the below graph:

As you can see, over the last 24h, the http_request_duration_seconds_count hasn't exceeded 800. As far as I understand, this metric indicates the cumulative count of HTTP requests over time.
How is it possible that I'm receiving 30req/s for some paths with the above query? If this volume was real, my cumulative request count over 24h should exceed 2.5M.
Updated Prometheus Screenshot:


Your second screenshot doesn't show http_request_duration_seconds_count but rather something calculated based on it. Is it rate? Could it be that you interpret second part wrongly?

@markalex I updated the question with the screenshot which includes the expression being queried for - as you can see it is simply the metric itself

<>_count supposed to behave as counter, and yours doesn't. This is the reason why you get unexpected results from rate. What is the reason for such a behaviour of <>_count - I don't know.
